# Listview highlight selected row with background image

Tags: android, listview, xamarin.android

I have an Android ListView that contains rows that each have a different background. I want to set a semi-transparent background when a row is selected, however I can't find a way to do this. All of the answers I've seen either use android:choiceMode and android:listSelector (which requires there to NOT be a background on the row view) or use a state list drawable (which requires a static image for the background, not dynamic images based on the data like in my case.)

```
<ListView
            android:id="@+id/properties_list"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:choiceMode="singleChoice" 
            android:listSelector="@android:color/darker_gray"
            android:divider="@color/white"
            android:dividerHeight="0dp" />
```

Any ideas how this can be accomplished?

[image]

As requested, here is the property row layout.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:rpr="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/search_list_item_height">
        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/property_row_details_container"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">
            <View
                android:id="@+id/property_row_border"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="3dp"
                android:background="@color/white"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:visibility="gone" />
            <RPR.Mobile.Droid.Widget.CachedImageView
                android:id="@+id/property_row_photo"
                android:layout_below="@+id/property_row_border"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="@dimen/search_list_item_height"
                android:scaleType="centerCrop" />
            <RelativeLayout
                android:id="@+id/property_row_highlight"
                android:layout_below="@+id/property_row_border"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:background="#99FEF0CC"
                android:visibility="gone" />
            <RPR.Mobile.Droid.Widget.CachedImageView
                android:id="@+id/property_row_gradient"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="@dimen/search_list_item_gradient_height"
                android:src="@drawable/property_row_gradient"
                android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" />
            <RPR.Mobile.Droid.Widget.ScaleImageView
                android:id="@+id/property_row_status"
                android:layout_below="@+id/property_row_border"
                android:layout_width="30dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true" />
            <RelativeLayout
                android:id="@+id/property_row_status_and_type_container"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/property_row_status"
                android:layout_width="@dimen/search_list_item_status_and_type_width"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignTop="@+id/property_row_status"
                android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/property_row_status"
                android:gravity="center_vertical"
                android:background="#80000000"
                android:paddingLeft="@dimen/padding_half">
                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/property_row_status_and_type"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:textSize="@dimen/search_list_item_text_size_small"
                    android:textColor="@color/white"
                    android:singleLine="true"
                    android:ellipsize="end" />
            </RelativeLayout>
            <RelativeLayout
                android:id="@+id/property_row_open_house_container"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/property_row_status_and_type_container"
                android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/property_row_photo_count_container"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignTop="@+id/property_row_status"
                android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/property_row_status"
                android:gravity="center_vertical"
                android:background="#CC000000"
                android:paddingLeft="@dimen/padding"
                android:paddingRight="@dimen/padding"
                android:visibility="gone">
                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/property_row_open_house"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:textSize="@dimen/search_list_item_text_size_small"
                    android:textColor="@color/yellow_gold"
                    android:singleLine="true"
                    android:ellipsize="end" />
            </RelativeLayout>
            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/property_row_photo_count_container"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignTop="@+id/property_row_status"
                android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/property_row_status"
                android_orientation="horizontal"
                android:gravity="center_vertical"
                android:background="#80000000"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:paddingLeft="@dimen/padding"
                android:paddingRight="@dimen/padding">
                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/property_row_photo_count"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:textSize="@dimen/search_list_item_text_size_small"
                    android:textColor="@color/white"
                    android:singleLine="true"
                    android:ellipsize="end" />
                <RPR.Mobile.Droid.Widget.CachedImageView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:src="@drawable/property_row_photo_count"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/padding_half" />
            </LinearLayout>
            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/property_row_more_open"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_alignParentBottom="true">
                <include
                    android:id="@+id/property_row_price_row"
                    layout="@layout/PropertyListRowPrice"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/padding"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/padding_half" />
                <include
                    android:id="@+id/property_row_lease_row"
                    layout="@layout/PropertyListRowPrice"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/padding"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/padding_half" />
                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/property_row_stats"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:textSize="@dimen/search_list_item_text_size_medium"
                    android:textColor="@color/white"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/padding"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/padding_half" />
                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/property_row_address"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:textSize="@dimen/search_list_item_text_size_address"
                    android:textColor="@color/white"
                    android:singleLine="true"
                    android:ellipsize="end"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/padding"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/padding" />
                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/property_row_apn"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:textSize="@dimen/search_list_item_text_size_medium"
                    android:textColor="@color/white"
                    android:singleLine="true"
                    android:ellipsize="none"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/padding"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/padding"
                    android:visibility="gone" />
                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/property_row_comps_button"
                    android:layout_width="200dp"
                    android:text="Add to Comps"
                    style="@style/Widget.Button.Rounded.Blue.WhiteText"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/padding"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/padding"
                    android:visibility="gone" />
            </LinearLayout>
            <RPR.Mobile.Droid.Widget.CachedImageView
                android:id="@+id/property_row_more_open"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:src="@drawable/property_row_more_off"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/padding"
                android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/padding" />
            <RPR.Mobile.Droid.Widget.CachedImageView
                android:id="@+id/property_row_save_status"
                android:layout_above="@+id/property_row_more_open"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:src="@drawable/property_row_saved"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/padding"
                android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/padding" />
        </RelativeLayout>
        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/property_row_more_container"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="@color/white"
            android:visibility="gone">
            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/property_row_more_top"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/padding"
                android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/padding"
                android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/padding">
                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/property_row_create_report"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    style="@style/Widget.TextView.BlueText.DrawableTop"
                    android:background="@android:color/transparent"
                    android:drawableTop="@drawable/property_row_create_report_selector"
                    android:text="Create Report"
                    android:textColor="@color/blue" />
                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/property_row_save"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    style="@style/Widget.TextView.BlueText.DrawableTop"
                    android:background="@android:color/transparent"
                    android:drawableTop="@drawable/property_row_save_selector"
                    android:text="Save Property"
                    android:textColor="@color/blue" />
                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/property_row_save_name"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    style="@style/Widget.TextView.BlueText.DrawableTop"
                    android:background="@android:color/transparent"
                    android:drawableTop="@drawable/property_row_save_name_selector"
                    android:text="Add Custom Name"
                    android:textColor="@color/blue" />
            </LinearLayout>
            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/property_row_more_bottom"
                android:layout_below="@+id/property_row_more_top"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/padding"
                android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/padding"
                android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/padding">
                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/property_row_add_note"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    style="@style/Widget.TextView.BlueText.DrawableTop"
                    android:background="@android:color/transparent"
                    android:drawableTop="@drawable/property_row_add_note_selector"
                    android:text="Add Note / Photo"
                    android:textColor="@color/blue" />
                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/property_row_call_agent"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    style="@style/Widget.TextView.BlueText.DrawableTop"
                    android:background="@android:color/transparent"
                    android:drawableTop="@drawable/property_row_call_agent_selector"
                    android:text="Call Agent"
                    android:textColor="@color/blue" />
                <View
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:visibility="invisible" />
            </LinearLayout>
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/property_row_more_address"
                android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/property_row_more_close"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textSize="@dimen/search_list_item_text_size_address"
                android:textColor="@color/blue"
                android:singleLine="true"
                android:ellipsize="end"
                android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/padding"
                android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/padding" />
            <RPR.Mobile.Droid.Widget.CachedImageView
                android:id="@+id/property_row_more_close"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:src="@drawable/property_row_more_on"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/padding"
                android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/padding" />
        </RelativeLayout>
    </RelativeLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Can i see your listview template??

Comment: @G.hakim Edited!

Comment: Did you try setting it to the background of the template